# Mybatis can't work when using "module-info.java"

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a demo project which worked perfect if not using "module-info.java"

the directory struct is as follow (using IDEA):

```
src
|-\main
|    |-\java
|    |    |-\org.example
|    |    |    |-\dao
|    |    |    |    ...
|    |    |    |-\model
|    |    |    |    ...
|    |    |    |-Main.java
|    |    |-module-info.java
|    |    
|    |-\resources 
|    |    |-\org.example
|    |    |    |-\dao
|    |    |    |   |-Mapper.xml 
|    |    |-mybatis-config.xml
```

The `module-info.java` file is:

```java
module org.example {
    requires org.xerial.sqlitejdbc;
    requires org.mybatis;

    opens org.example.dao;
    exports org.example;
}
```

In the `mybatis-config.xml` file, the mapper is used as:

```xml
<mappers>
   <mapper resource="org/example/dao/Mapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

When I delete the `module-info.java` file, everything is okay. But when I added the `module-info.java` file, the `Sqlsessionfactory` can't be built. The following is the code:

```java
try{
    String RESOURCE = "mybatis-config.xml";
    Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(RESOURCE);
    SqlSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();
    SqlSessionFactory factory = builder.build(reader); // This statement won't be executed correctly, and there is no exception throwed, or maybe there is but I can't catch it, I don't know why.
    SqlSession session = factory.openSession(); // the session is null
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace() // the exception can't be catched.
}
```

All the exception I got is just a `NullPointerException` which is caused by the null value of the sqlsession.

So, what's wrong about my project with "module-info.java" file?

Comment: "Not executed correctly without exception" does not make sense. And `openSession()` does not return `null`.  You are editing a different file, maybe? :D

Comment: @ave Sorry for my weak English. "Not executed correctly without exception"  is the past comment, I don't know why you can still see it. Last night I debuged my code, I steped into the `builder.build()` method, and found the code failed at creating `XMLConfigBuilder`, and then I just created the `XMLConfigBuilder` by myself, finally I catched the exception successfully and I got the solution. The solution is to add the `requires java.sql;` to the `module-info.java`.  : )

Comment: @ave "Not executed correctly without exception" means the statement can't be executed successfully, and there is no exception catched. It just skips the `openSession()` line and the `catch(){...}` codes, thus the session is not initialized and the value is null.

Comment: I still see that statement in the code comment  Anyway, I'm happy to know the issue has been resolved.